# Excel - date - vba textbox to table

Tags: excel, vba, date, excel-2010

I have below vba for userform text box that sets todays date. Now when the data is entered into the table in my product listing sheet the date is reformatted.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
txt_date.Value = Format(Date, "d/m/yyyy")
End Sub
```

So when the data is added into the sheet it makes it m/d/yyyy.

Comment: i am not understanding why the d is changing to m?

Answer (score 1):

The data type used in your VBA + the way you write back to your sheet will influence how Excel will interpret your data. Have a look at beyond examples:

```
Sub TestDate()
    Dim datestr As String, dateDate As Date
    
    datestr = "11/05/2021"
    dateDate = "11/05/2021"
    
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = CDate(datestr)
    Sheet1.Range("C1").Value = dateDate
    
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Value2 = CDate(datestr)
    Sheet1.Range("C2").Value2 = dateDate
End Sub
```

By using "value2" you see how the raw data of a var defined as "date" type is send back to Excel. imho this is the best way, but you'll have to set the correct format directly in your Excel sheet (select column > Format Cell > Date => choose the format you want (you could set this in vba as well but I don't think it's needed here).

best of luck,

Comment: and add vote please. Cause this matter is not been seen online so far I researched. It is a bit unique issue and still I cannot see a clear solution.

Comment: I updated my answer. let me know if it's still not clear

Comment: Well, thanks. But you need to udnerstand.I am using a form which has a textboc called tex_date and the todays date is shown whenever the form is opened. This is all fine. When the user clicks Add button to add all the information, the date is getting wrongly formatted. I will show the code below for the text_date used in the Add button:


.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.txt_date.Value

Comment: Convert the var (of type "string") from your form to date datatype before pasting it to the sheet: .Cells(iRow, 8).Value2 = CDate(Me.txt_date). I updated the answer. The var of type string will now be shown as "44327" (when using value2) or as date (value) when looking at it in the Excel sheet.